# How do I track number of rows updated

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm using sql2000 but I'm also using mysql, and sql2008 and am interested in how to count the number of updates I justed updated?   I do see where there is an updated table but not sure if that's within a normal query. thx

```
declare @updateCount as int
set @updateCount = 0
begin transaction
set @updateCount = update GENIUSES set IQ=161 where IQ=86 and username like 'RetroCoder'
print @updateCount
if @updateCount = 1 
  commit
else
  rollback
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @updateCount INT;
UPDATE dbo.GENIUSES set IQ=161 where IQ=86 and username like 'RetroCoder';
SELECT @updateCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: Do you have a mysql example by any chance?

Comment: Sorry, not a MySQL guy, but please [check the docs for the ROW_COUNT() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).

Answer (score 3):

```
Declare @count  int
update GENIUSES set IQ=161 where IQ=86 and username like 'RetroCoder'
Set @count =  @@Rowcount
select @count
```